# How to get the value in a nested loop [on condition]

Tags: python-2.7, refactoring, conditional-statements

I am a beginner in python.I have two lists and I have to get the unmatched ones from the first. for example.

```
list_one= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list_two = ['d', 'c', 'b']
```

my output has to be ['a']

right now, I am using nested loop with a flag stating that the element is there or not. I am thinking there might be a cleaner way than this.

```
for doc in list1:
  item_exist = False
  for doc2 in list:
    if doc.lower() == doc2.lower():
      item_exist = True
      break
  if not item_exist:
    result.append(doc1)
```

Is there a way where I can simplify the code?

Comment: if you do not care about the order [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html?highlight=set#module-sets)s are the way to go: `diff = set(list_one) - set(list_two)`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.